# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, logic

my code for a rock paper scissors game (called toss) is as follows:

```
var toss = function (one,two) {
    if(one = "rock" && two = "rock") {
        console.log("Tie! Try again!");
    }
    // more similar conditions with `else if`
};
```

When I enter in the parameters

```
toss("rock","rock")
```

I get this error code:

> "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

How to fix it? What this error means and what other cases when this error can happen?

Comment: The three "tie" cases can be simplified into a single `if( one == two)`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have to use `==` to compare (or even `===`, if you want to compare types). A single `=` is for assignment.

```
if (one == 'rock' && two == 'rock') {
    console.log('Tie! Try again!');
}
```

Comment: for clarification, what would the difference be between == and ===?

Comment: The above comment is sort of wrong, ECMA specifies that this is not a type check, it does an operation called type coercion. This is really useful to know, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript

Comment: @Kevin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 11):

Common reasons for the error:

- use of assignment (`=`) instead of equality (`==`/`===`)
- assigning to result of function `foo() = 42` instead of passing arguments (`foo(42)`)
- simply missing member names (i.e. assuming some default selection) : `getFoo() = 42` instead of `getFoo().theAnswer = 42` or array indexing `getArray() = 42` instead of `getArray()[0]= 42`

In this particular case you want to use `==` (or better `===` - [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)) to check for equality (like `if(one === "rock" && two === "rock")`, but it the actual reason you are getting the error is trickier.

The reason for the error is [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). In particular we are looking for `&&` (precedence 6) and `=` (precedence 3).

Let's put braces in the expression according to priority - `&&` is higher than `=` so it is executed first similar how one would do `3+4*5+6` as `3+(4*5)+6`:

```
 if(one= ("rock" && two) = "rock"){...
```

Now we have expression similar to multiple assignments like `a = b = 42` which due to right-to-left associativity executed as `a = (b = 42)`. So adding more braces:

```
 if(one= (  ("rock" && two) = "rock" )  ){...
```

Finally we arrived to actual problem: `("rock" && two)` can't be evaluated to l-value that can be assigned to (in this particular case it will be *value* of `two` as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)).

Note that if you'd use braces to match *perceived priority* surrounding each "equality" with braces you get no errors. Obviously that also producing different result than you'd expect - changes value of both variables and than do `&&` on two strings `"rock" && "rock"` resulting in `"rock"` (which in turn is truthy) all the time due to behavior of [logial &&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
if((one = "rock") && (two = "rock"))
{
   // always executed, both one and two are set to "rock"
   ...
}
```

---

For even more details on the error and other cases when it can happen - see specification:

[Assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13)

> LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression 
>   ... 
>   Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true:
>   ... 
>   IsStrictReference(lref) is true

[Left-Hand-Side Expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2)

and [The Reference Specification Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) explaining IsStrictReference:

> ... function calls are permitted to return references. This possibility is admitted purely for the sake of host objects. No built-in ECMAScript function defined by this specification returns a reference and there is no provision for a user-defined function to return a reference...

Comment: Good tip. Also, to add some information, I had this error in my code once, and coudn´t find out why, because it was kind of simple. I was using inline javascript, for example: <a onmouseover="imgIte123-a.src='layout-bto-gol.png';"> and it was returning me this error. The problem was with the dash in the id. I had to change the id to imgIte123_a and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened for me with `eslint` module. EsLinter throw `Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` for await in second if statement.

```
if (condition_one) {
  let result = await myFunction()
}

if (condition_two) {
  let result = await myFunction() // eslint parsing error
}
```

As strange as it sounds what fixed this error was to add **; semicolon** at the end of line where await occurred.

```
if (condition_one) {
  let result = await myFunction();
}

if (condition_two) {
  let result = await myFunction();
}
```