# Calling a function without parentheses returns whole function as a string

Tags: javascript, function

I created a JavaScript object like this:

```
var obj = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  add: function(){
     return this.a + this.b;
  }
};
```

I executed the function as `obj.add` and it returns the whole function as string a like this:

```
function(){
  return this.a + this.b;
}

But later, I tried to call the function again, including the parentheses, like `obj.add()` and it returns the value `30`. I couldn’t figure out why I get such a different output upon calling the function with `obj.add` and with `obj.add()`. What is the main difference between calling an object’s function with parentheses and without parentheses?
```

Comment: You can't *call* a function without parenthesis.  Adding `()` is how you call a function.  Without the `()`, you are just getting the function itself.  In JavaScript, functions are just variables, like strings or ints or whatever.

Comment: `add` is [a `Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). When you use it without the parenthesis, you're *most likely* converting it to a `string` through the caller's [type coercion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)

Comment: but as i see in dev tools i by calling obj.add i am not getting object, but litteral string. i dont get this

Comment: @blgt You're not converting it to a string, the console converted it to a string so it can display it,

Comment: @AmbesagerEstifanos, the default behavior of console is to convert it to a string. Try doing `console.log(typeof(ambes.add))` and you should get 'function'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without parentheses, you're retrieving a reference to the function, you are not calling (executing) the function

With parentheses, you're executing the function.

```js
function a() {
  return 2;
}

var b = a(); // called a, b is now 2;
var c = a; // c is referencing the same function as a
console.log(c); // console will display the text of the function in some browsers
var d = c(); // But it is indeed a function, you can call c(), d is now 2;
```

Comment: `c is the same thing as a now` not true, it's passed by value, not reference. Changing `c` won't change `a`, nor vice-versa.

Comment: @Shomz OK, `c` now references the same function object as `a` does.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't execute the function with `obj.add`, you only looked it up in the object and the environment you're in happened to render the function as a string. You execute it by adding the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Without the parenthesis you're not really calling anything, nor are you returning anything, it's just a reference !

I'm guessing you did something like this

```
var result = ambes.add;

console.log(result);
```

and that doesn't call the function, it logs the *actual content of the `add` property*, which **is** the function, and logging a function will log the string content of the function, not what it would return had you called it.

Comment: Technically you are returning the function object itself. You could thereafter call `result()` to execute the function and receive any returned value.

Comment: your code also result same , the whole function as string

Comment: @musicfuel - isn't that what I wrote ".. content of the add property, which **is** the function" ?

Comment: @AmbesagerEstifanos - Uhm, yes! The code posted does exactly what you described, it doesn't solve the issue, as there is no way to solve this, other than adding the parenthesis.

Comment: @adeneo, yes. I was clarifying to the 'Without the parenthesis you're not really calling anything, nor are you returning anything'.

Comment: @musicfuel - Oh okay, I could probably be clearer on the fact that it's a reference, added!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: `functionName` just returns the function body, while `functionName()` executes the function and returns its return value (or `undefined`, if there's no explicit return). The same principle works for when a function is an object property, like you had `obj.add`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function requires the () because they are the function invocation operator. To execute a function you will always need to include parentheses.

When you call `ambes.add` you are returning the function object itself. If you do so inside `console.log()` or concatenate it onto a string JavaScript will return the function definition as a complete string which explains the first output you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You must use () to call a function in JavaScript.

If you do not use parenthesis, you are simply referencing the function, which can be useful in a case where you would like to pass a function to another code block for deferred execution.

In your situation, because you wish to call add right away, you should be sure to use ()

```
obj.add();
```