# Why in Javascript '' == '0' is false but 0 == '' is true?

Tags: javascript

I saw an exciting and confusing issue. Based on "JavaScript, the good parts" :

```
'' == '0'           // false
0 == ''             // true
```

So, why?!

Comment: tl;dr type coercion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons for more.

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @Dom Interestingly, PHP considers `"0"` to be a falsy string, presumably because databases pass all values as strings and so a "false" value from a database needed to be considered falsy. Really, really hacky and annoying at times XD

Comment: Not sure why it confuses you that comparing different values gives a different result.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: Because it is.

Advanced answer:

- `'' == '0'` compares the items as strings, since they're both strings. No type changes needed, just compare. They're blatantly different, so `false`.
- `0 == ''` compares the items as numbers. `''` converts to `0` so they are the same.

But really, who cares?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, both are of type `String` and hence do not equate, as they are compared by their values.

In the second case, the left hand side is a `Number`, so there is a conversion occurring, which makes `''` to `0` 
and hence `true`

`==` results in typecasting and then comparing, if needed. `===` doesn't typecast, so

```
0 === '' // false
```