# Compare x ='' and x = 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have the following:

```
var a = 0;

if (Number(a) != '')
{
    alert('hi');
}
```

I never get the alert even though a is not empty, it is 0 and I need this value for numeric calculations.`enter code here`

What's going on here?

Comment: That's because of implicit type-coercion due to `!=`, use `!==`. And both empty string and number 0 are **falsy** values.

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```js
var a = 0;

if (Number(a) !== '') {
  alert('hi');
}
```

If you compare two values using `==` or `!=` operator, javascript [type-coerces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript) both of them and then compares. On the contrary, if you use `===` instead of `==` (or `!==` instead of `!=`), type coercion does not happen.

Comment: The answer shows the correct way to get the code to behave as expected, but does not explain *why*

Answer (score 2):

The `!=` operator does type conversion if needed, so `''` is converted to the numeric value `0`.

You can use the `!==` operator to avoid the type conversion:

```
var a = 0;

if (Number(a) !== '')
{
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Excellent that worked, !== flew right over my head as I have been doing way too much C# progamming !

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing 0 != 0 which will always be false.

The main issue is that the implicit cast here is causing `''` to become `0`. This can be easily verified.

```js
alert(Number(''));//0
```

But why does this happen? It is defined behavior in the Language Specification as seen at

- **9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type**
  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1

  > The conversion of a String to a Number value is similar overall to the determination of the Number value for a numeric literal (see 7.8.3), but some of the details are different, so the process for converting a String numeric literal to a value of Number type is given here in full. This value is determined in two steps: first, a mathematical value (MV) is derived from the String numeric literal; second, this mathematical value is rounded as described below.
  >
  > **The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0.**

This is why the value of implicitly converting an empty string to a number is 0.

Going forward, it would make more sense to check for a number by using [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to ensure that a number was entered by the user or is present in the variable.

```js
var a = 0;

if (!isNaN(a))
{
    alert('a is a number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the !== operator to avoid type conversion