# Difference between ! operator and $.IsNumeric in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a condition that needs to be validated with a string on one side and a decimal in the other side. However if the second condition is null this should return true, to enter and display my is required message.

```
if (!equipObject[i].Mass[0].massId  && !equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price ) {
    // display message - either massId or Price are required!
}
```

however I am thinking about changing the second condition

```
!equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price
```

for

```
!$.isNumeric(equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price)
```

How are these two validations different? which one is optimal? 0 is not a valid price according to the BL.

Comment: They behave differently for values of `0` and all values that are not numbers. So which to use depends on your use case.

Comment: The first one converts whatever is in the `Price` property and coerces it to boolean. This could cause issues where a valid value is coerced incorrectly - eg `0` would be `false`, yet `0` may be valid for your logic.

Comment: don't think so.. 0 is a number

Comment: @SugatoSengupta Who are you responding to?

Comment: To OP. Sorry for not mentioning lol.

Comment: `!value` will be satisfied for all falsey conditions. `!$.isNumeric` will satisfy for all non numeric value. Both are very different.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### TL;DR

They're very different and do essentially totally different things

---

```
!equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price
```

Here you take a "value" and it's [coerced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript) into a true/false value and then a "not" is applied. So if we replace `equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price` with actual values you get the following results:

```
!0 //true
!1 //false
!2 //false
!0.00 //true
!1.8884441 //false
!"1.8884441" //false
!"one" //false
!true //false
!false //true
!null //true
```

Etc. So this isn't very type safe.

```
!$.isNumeric(equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price)
```

this utilises [jQuery's isNumeric function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).

> The `$.isNumeric()` method checks whether its argument represents a
>   numeric value. If so, it returns `true`. Otherwise it returns `false`. The
>   argument can be of any type.

So let's do the same:

```
!$.isNumeric(0) //false
!$.isNumeric(1) //false
!$.isNumeric(2) //false
!$.isNumeric(0.00) //false
!$.isNumeric(1.8884441) //false
!$.isNumeric("1.8884441") //false
!$.isNumeric("one") //true
!$.isNumeric(true) //true
!$.isNumeric(false) //true
!$.isNumeric(null) //true
```

so very different results.

> which one is optimal?

That depends on your definition of optimal. I'm presuming you actually want to check if something is an integer and greater than zero, in which case I think you need a third way:

```
!$.isNumeric(equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price) && equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price !== 0
```

notice the `!==`. [This prevents coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: actually  my value is a decimal( 0.00 ), and yes my validation should exclude that 0 as a invalid price( BL decision).

Comment: I think this would do the trick:   !$.isNumeric(equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price) || equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price !== 0, since I want to display the message if either the value is null(the object is null) or the value is 0, since is not a valid price according to my business logic.

Comment: Added some more examples to illustrate. It's pretty easy to test yourself: [try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ht7uuvn7/)

Comment: actually your presumption was right was what I was looking. good answer and good examples.

Comment: Can anyone explain the -1?

Answer (score 0):

If `equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price` is `0`:

```
!0 // is true
!$.isNumeric(0) // is false
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, CRec,

In this case `!equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price` you are testing the object, if they exist and has value.

In this case `!$.isNumeric(equipObject[i].Mass[0].Price.` you are testing if the value are a numeric valor.

If you need to confirm the price is always numeric, the second one is the best, you are guaranteed you have a price higher than 0 in the variable.