# Confusion about relationship between Boolean value "true" and string

Tags: javascript

```
if(true){
    alert("hello");
}

if("string"){
    alert("hello");
}
```

The code above shows that a string can be used as a substitute for Boolean value "true". Why does this work and does this mean that Boolean value "true" and string have the same data type?

Comment: Guess what? `"false"` evaluates to `true` as well. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: `"string"` does not evaluate to `false`.

Comment: just to be sure , You can use "string"==true or "string"===true in Your Condition  .  but console.log("string"==true) or console.log("string"===true)  will return false just check it in your console of your browser

Answer (score 1):

A `string` as a statement, represents it's existence, in other words, if the `string` is set, it will return `true`, as if its `""` it will return as `false`

This way you can check a variable if it is set or not

Comment: A string can't be `null`. A _variable_ may contain the `null` value, but if it has that value it isn't a string. However, the string value `""` is also falsy. See the MDN link in haim770's comment for details of truthy and falsy values.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's conditional operators such as `if-else` and `a ? b : c` don't require the condition to be of actual `Boolean` type but rather check whether it is `truthy` or a `falsy` value in JavaScript terms.

For example, such values as `null` and `0` are considered `falsy` so they would be treated like `false` in `if-else` and ternary operators.

In a broader sense this might be considered as a case of type coercion, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript) for more information. So when an interpreter sees non-boolean expression inside an `if` it is "re-writing" it like `if (Boolean("string")) { ... }`, i.e. invoking conversion from the expression to the exact boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if("string"){
    alert("hello");
}
```

since you did not include an operator, as default, it just checks for the existence of the string, `"string" == true`.

Comment: It's not really checking for the _existence_ of the string. The string `""` exists but is falsy.

Comment: oh, thanks for the point out. what would be a more appropriate answer to this question?

Comment: You're pretty close, perhaps if you read the MDN article that haim770's comment links to it will give some ideas on how to understand and answer the question better.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a boolean type, with possible values true and false (both of which are keywords.) Any value can be converted to a boolean according to the following rules:
false, 0, empty strings (""), NaN, null, and undefined all become false.
All other values become true.

You can perform this conversion explicitly using the Boolean() function:

Boolean(""); // false
Boolean(234); // true

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript