# Why does adding "{" "}" remove brackets from an array? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

Example:

```
var test = [];
test.push( 'string', 'test'); //[ 'string', 'test' ]
console.log('{' + test + '}'); // {string,test}
console.log(typeof('{' + test + '}')); //string
```

How come adding the `{` and `}` removes the brackets from test? I would have expected the result of the third line to be `{ [string, test] }`

Comment: Try just `console.log(''+test)` - the string representation of an array doesn't have brackets.

Comment: The `+` punctuator is overloaded. It can mean [arithmetic addition, string concatenation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) or the [unary `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-unary-plus-operator). Which one is based on context.

Comment: `'' + test` coerces `test` to a string: `test.toString()` gives the same result.

Comment: JS is a very loosely typed language. In the operations involving different types the type coercion from objects to primitives like String or Boolean are performed automatically. In this particular case the `Array.prototype.toString()` function just neglects the outer brackets and does the opposite of `String.prototype.split(",")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS performs
[type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)
or
[type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion)
, which means that when 2 different data types are used together in an expression, we get an "equivalent" type.

#### Example

We know that `true` and `false` are booleans, not numbers.
But we can still use them as numbers, because due to type coercion, `true == 1` and `false == 0`.

Not that I am using `==` and not `===`.

Similarly, we can do:

```
var a = 123;
var b = a + 1;     // 124
var c = a + true;  // 124
var d = a + '1';   // 1231
```

---

In your case, you are coercing an aray and a string. And the JS engine coerces the array to string type:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
console.log(a)              // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(a + '')         // "1,2,3"
console.log('{' + a + '}')  // "{1,2,3}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is one of the many bad choices made when Javascript was created, and now it's too late to fix because of backward compatibiity.

An array when converted to a string becomes the concatenation of the elements converted to strings, separated by commas **without wrapping `[` `]` markers**.

This for example is the reason for which

```
(1 == [1])
```

is `true` in Javascript (the two have different types and their conversion to string is identical), and the reason for which defining

```
var a = [1], b = 1, c = [[1]];
```

the expression

```
(a == b && b == c && a != c)
```

is also `true`.

Comment: Why is having the string representation of an array be the element values separated by commas a bad choice when JavaScript was created? Is there a better default option that could've been implemented for when converting an array to a string?

Comment: @nnnnnn: `[1, 2, 3]` being translated for example to `"[1, 2, 3]"` would have been better (it's what Python does). Sure most of the crazyness of `==` comes from implicit conversions (Javascript would have been better with `===` being the "default" comparison) but array->string rule adds some extra weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is very flexible, unfortunately in this case it's very very flexible for us understand. So what's happen in below code

```
console.log('{' + test + '}');
```

test is an `Array` object, but when you try to combine it with another string, JavaScript will see everything are strings, in this case `test` will be converted to `string,test`.
The converting way like [Array.prototype.toString()](http://Array.prototype.toString()).
The same thing with weak comparison (`==`). So we can use trick comparison (`===`) to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

That is because, when you do: `'' + test`; you will get string: `string,test`

for `Array` object, if it combined with any string, it will be converted to string with format: `element1,element2,element3`