# In javascript, why is the string "true", after coercion, still not equal to boolean true?

Tags: javascript, types, casting

In javascript, `String(true) == "true"` evaluates to true, and `Boolean("true") == true` evaluates to true, so why does `"true" == true` evaluate to false?

[image]

Comment: not following your logic...why should it?

Comment: Because JavaScript?

Comment: maybe you get confused using `Boolean("true")`, since `Boolean("false")` also returns true.

Comment: Per the Boolean docs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean): _"If the value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. If the DOM object document.all is passed as a parameter, the new boolean object also has an initial value of false. **All other values, including any object or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true**."_

Comment: Answers on [What exactly is Type Coercion in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19915688/215552) could be helpful.

Comment: Note, that you've thrown the result of the type coersion away.

Comment: My understanding is that the coercion comparator should coerce the left side to the type of the right side, which seems like it should coerce to `true == true`

Comment: @Dusty, that is a wrong assumption. The coercion in this case is to number.

Comment: Yeah, so nothing is ever coerced to Boolean! Who knew (you guys, I guess!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `"true" == true` the coercion is to number. So this becomes:

```
NaN == 1
```

... which is `false`.

The [loose equality operands table on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) might be useful to check out.

Comment: Crazy. This matches Hennek's answer that Boolean gets converted to number, no matter which side of the comparator it's on, apparently?

Comment: That conversion does not always happen for booleans (as the table on mozilla.org also shows), but in practical terms you can think of it that way: the outcome of the loose equality will be consistent with it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) (Mozilla Developer Network). When we compare two operands of differents types, *[the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm] will attempt to convert them to the same type before making the comparison*.

Finally, the answer is the following:

> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to 1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.

Then

> When comparing a number and a string, the string is converted to a number value. JavaScript attempts to convert the string numeric literal to a Number type value. First, a mathematical value is derived from the string numeric literal. Next, this value is rounded to nearest Number type value.

So, finally, we compare `Nan == 1` which is `false` as pointed by @trincot.