# Using Javascript, I cannot get IF statements in an onchange function to fire properly

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Using Javascript, I am trying to fire a function when a change is made to a `select` dropdown menu.

The HTML is:

```
<select id="select" onchange="characterchange()">
  <option value="spidey">Spider-Man
  <option value="panther">Black Panther
</select>

<div id="Spidey">
  <h2 style="color: red">Spider-Man</h2>
    ...
    ...
</div>

<div id="Panther">
  <h2 style="color: black">Panther</h2>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

The JS is:

```
function characterchange() {
  console.log("fired characterchange");

  var character = document.getElementById("select").value;
  console.log(character);

  if (character = "Spider-Man") {
    console.log("selected spidey");
    document.getElementById("Spidey").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("Panther").style.display = "none";
    console.log("showing Spidey");
  }
  if (character = "Black Panther") {
    console.log("selected panther");
    document.getElementById("Spidey").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Panther").style.display = "inline";
    console.log("showing Panther");
  }
}
```

I'm getting logs for `fired characterchange`, `character`, `selected spidey`, and `selected panther` when any change is made. The CSS is not being changed and the logs that follow that code aren't firing. What am I missing?

Edit: Making the change to `===` fires the correct if statement however, my function stops after `"selected spidey"` or `"selected panther"`.

Comment: You meant to use `===` not `=`. The former is for equality, the latter for assignment.

Comment: ^ or you could use `==`. Do read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons#359509

Comment: @elclanrs Doing that fires the correct if statement however, my function stops after `"selected spidey"` or `"selected panther"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check this updated code which is working.**

First you should make == symbol inside if condition.

Then change the value within if condition.

```js
function characterchange() {
console.log("fired characterchange");

var character = document.getElementById("select").value;

if (character == "spidey") {
    console.log("selected spidey");
    document.getElementById("Spidey").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("Panther").style.display = "none";
    console.log("showing Spidey");
}

if (character == "panther") {
    console.log("selected panther");
    document.getElementById("Spidey").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Panther").style.display = "inline";
    console.log("showing Panther");
}
}
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="characterchange()">
  <option value="spidey">Spider-Man</option>
  <option value="panther">Black Panther</option>
</select>

<div id="Spidey">
  <h2 style="color: red">Spider-Man</h2>
</div>

<div id="Panther">
  <h2 style="color: black">Panther</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (character = "Spider-Man")`

translates into

`if ("Spider-Man") // at this point character variable will have the "Spider-Man" value, as @Teemu correctly pointed out`

which, due to [JS coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript),  **always** translates into

`if (true)`

What you meant is

`if (character === "Spider-Man") // === (comparison) not = (assignment)`

Comment: Worth nothing to mention, that as a side effect "Spider-Man" is also assigned to `character`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the aim is but pretty much all is wrong. As others have hinted, = is assignemnt, while == or === check for equality.

next you have:

```
 var character = document.getElementById("select").value;
```

here, you are getting value of the select. Then below, you are comparing with the text value of the element. So instead of

```
   if (character = "Spider-Man") {
```

do:

```
 if (character == "spidey") {
```

Here is a full page:

```
       <script>
    function characterchange() {
      console.log("fired characterchange");

      var character = document.getElementById("select").value;
      console.log(character);

      if (character == "spidey") {
        console.log("selected spidey");
        document.getElementById("Spidey").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("Panther").style.display = "none";
        console.log("showing Spidey");
      }
      if (character == "panther") {
        console.log("selected panther");
        document.getElementById("Spidey").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("Panther").style.display = "block";
        console.log("showing Panther");
      }
    }

    </script>
```

and the HTML:

```
    <select id="select" onchange="characterchange()">
          <option value="spidey">Spider-Man
          <option value="panther">Black Panther
        </select>

        <div id="Spidey">
          <h2 style="color: red">Spider-Man</h2>
            ...
            ...
        </div>

        <div id="Panther">
          <h2 style="color: black">Panther</h2>
          ...
          ...
        </div>
```