# Why JavaScript does not evaluate "1-1" to 0 in an operation as "123" to 123 while doing calculation

Tags: javascript, string, types, ecmascript-6, int

> "123" is a string type but the  value is an integer. So JavaScript convert it to an integer on compile time and allowed multiplication,Addition,etc. But "1-2" is a string type but why it does not allow to multiplication? And why  JavaScript does not handle this?

```js
console.log("1" * "123")//123
console.log(1 * "123")//123
console.log("1" * 123)//123

console.log("ABC" * 123)//NaN
console.log("ABC" * "ABC")//NaN

console.log("0" * "1-2")//NAN
console.log("0" * "1*2")//NAN
console.log("0" * "1+2")//NAN
console.log("0" * "1/2")//NAN
console.log("0" * (1-2))//0
```

### EDIT:

- *`-`is not `subtraction` but a `hyphen`. OK. But it should be handle as `hyphen` while **concatenation** not **calculation**.*

> Why JavaScript can't  subtract/Add  "1-1" while compiling. But JavaScript  convert "123" as a integer on compile time, if the code is doing calculation. Then why  it's doesn't  calculate "1-1" or "1+1" to `0` or `2` and convert into an integer?

Comment: This is because in "1-2" is taken the - is not "substraction" but a hyphen '-' character.

Comment: You need to read about coercion - [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144

Comment: @RameshRajendran Maybe it should, it's just that it doesn't. See chŝdk's Answer.

Comment: @Exception_al I don't know why 3 down votes for my question. Is it a bad question?

Comment: I didn't downvote ... I liked the question, even did some `console.log` to verify ! There you go -- an UpVote to have caught my wonder !

Comment: I think that it is a design choice. It is just how it works.

Comment: `"1-2"` is a string, `1-2` is an expression, i.e. code. JavaScript converts strings to numbers in numeric context (when the string is one operand of `*`, `-`, `/` etc) but it doesn't attempt to evaluate the expressions embedded in the string. There is a special function for this purpose, assuming the string contains code (and you know what you're doing).

Comment: @axiac then what is `"123"` this is also a string right? But how it's doing calculation in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you read my previous comment? Read it again! Then read this fragment of documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Numbers_vs._strings

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if JavaScript correctly parsed string "A perfect website code" and inferred all the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well to evaluate these strings as `Number` you can use `eval()` function, ***but*** **it's not very recommended** to use it. So `eval("1-2");` will give you `-1`.

---

But in javascript when you use an operator, it will try to evaluate both operands to numbers before doing the operation. So in all cases the two parts of the operation will be evaluated to numbers.

**Edit:**

Actually in an operation `JavaScript`, parses only `strings` that can be parsed as `Number`, `"1-2"`, can't be parsed as a `Number`. To check that try to execute `Number("1-2");` you will get `NaN`.

So when you evaluate:

- `"123"` you will get `123`.
- `"ABC"` you will get `NaN`.
- `"(1-2)"` you will get `NaN`.
- `("1-2")` you will get `NaN`.

And in `("1-2")` the string `"1-2"` won't be evaluated to `1-2` because `-` in a string won't be considered as an operator.

So conclusion is when you you have a string that can't be parsed/evaluated as a number, you will get `NaN`.

**Documentation:**

For further details you can check [**Expressions** section of MDN's **Expressions and operators** Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions), where it says:

**Arithmetic**: evaluates to a number, for example 3.14159. (Generally uses arithmetic operators.)

Comment: Please read  my question again. I want to ask that in the comment. but i update that commonly for my question.

Comment: No, `"(1-2)" you will get -1.` , it doesn't. While coercing it cannot evaluate string with "symbols" to a result. It can simply convert it to a `number` if the string is plain and simple digits. Otherwise NaN it is !

Comment: @Exception_al Yup. I agree. that's also given `NaN`

Comment: @chŝdk : Please see my edit. Make the modification (accept my edit or fix it yourself) and I take my "Downvote" back :)

Comment: @RameshRajendran Actually in an operation JavaScript, parses only strings that can be parsed as `Number`, "1-2", can't be parsed as a Number.

Comment: @chŝdk Yes Agree. But my question is **why it can't?**. I am not sure with **ECM** script

Comment: @RameshRajendran It's the specification of Javascript, it was designed this way.

Comment: @RameshRajendran You can use `eval()` function, but it's not recommended. `eval("1-2");` will give `-1`.

Comment: It will be evaluated also, and will give you `-3`.

Comment: I hope `Eval()` function is the correct answer for this question. could you please add this in your answer to make `MarkAsAnswer` :)

Answer (score 1):

Because Javascript is treating the `"2-1"` as a `String`. When trying to do arithmetic Javascript will attempt to convert the `String` into an `Int`. Since `"2-1"` is recognized as a whole string it won't reduce to just one which is why you see the `NaN`.

Comment: Please read  my question again. I want to ask that in the comment. but i update that commonly for my question.