# Confusion in javascript's logical operator

Tags: javascript

I am confusing with following outputs.

```
> console.log('0&&1')
0&&1 // ok  
> console.log(0&&1)
0 //ok
```

But when i console this below expression then it give 1. So please help me to understand this concept

```
> console.log('0&&1'+0&&1)
1
```

Comment: As with other questions of this nature, I have to ask, who cares? If you're trying to add a string and a number with a boolean operator in the mix, you're just asking for trouble and should go do something more sensible :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` has higher precedence than `&&`. So your last snippet is essentially equivalent to:

```
console.log(('0&&1' + 0) && 1)
```

which will become this:

```
console.log('0&&10' && 1)
```

Since a non-empty string is a truthy value, thus, the return value is 1.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is related to [type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)