# Logic Gates using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

New to HTML and JavaScript and I am attempting to make a webpage which let the user choose which gate they would like to use e.g.

```
AND

OR

XOR

NAND

NOR
```

The user enters their choice through a dropdown box then they choose the values to enter either `1` or `0`.

This is all I have for the function right now, I was using the console.log to test if it was receiving the choice properly which it does, but I don't know how to move forwards from here and how to run the logic gates.

```js
 function Logic() {
         console.log("Invoked Logic")
        if (document.getElementById('gate').value == "1")
            console.log("1")
        else if (document.getElementById('gate').value == "2") {
            console.log("2")
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('gate').value == "3") {
            console.log("3")
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('gate').value == "4") {
            console.log("4")
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('gate').value == "5") {
            console.log("5")
        }
        else {
            alert("Not a valid option.");
        }
    }
```

```html
        <label>Which Logic Gate would you like?</label> <select id="gate">
    <option value ="d"> Please Select</option>
       <option value="1" >AND</option>
        <option value ="2">OR</option>
        <option value="3">XOR</option>
        <option value ="4">NAND</option>
        <option value="5">NOR</option>
</select> <br> <br>



        <label>What value would you like the second input to be?</label> <select id="v2">
    <option value ="d"> Please Select</option>
    <option value="b1">0</option>
    <option value ="b2">1</option>
</select>
```

and for the value of 1 or 0 I use another drop down (two of them).

How would I go about getting the value of the two dropdowns then inputting them into the corresponding logic gates?

**edit** seems as though all of my if statements are pushing this error onto me.

> Unexpected type coercion

I was able to fix it by using triple equals.

That isn't the main problem, my problem is that I do not understand how I can convert my two dropdown values which are strings into booleans themself and then run that into a logic gate equation.

An example of this if the user chose the "AND" gate and a `1` and `0`. The `1` and `0` are converted into booleans so 1 being true and 0 being false and then outputting the result of them being ran through a logic gate so `0`.

Comment: Consider using [switch-case](https://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/switch) for the first snippet.

Comment: Type coercion is the process of converting a value from one type to another type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript covers this very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)

Comment: Off-topic but... Your code is so repetative. At least extract this part `document.getElementById('gate').value` to a variable.

Comment: I'm quite new to HTML and javascript so I can only use simple methods really.

Comment: Do you know how all these `XOR`, `NAND` should work? If yes, then it's straight forward to apply comparison and show value to user, otherwise you should investigate them first.

Comment: I know how they all work, its just writing it in javascript as efficiently as possible as I lack the skills currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attached the logic function to the change event of the select boxes. Checked if they all had a valid value. If so calculate the result based on the used gate.

```js
/* 
document.getElementById('gate').addEventListener('change', logic);
document.getElementById('v1').addEventListener('change', logic);
document.getElementById('v2').addEventListener('change', logic);
*/
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click', logic);

function logic() {
  var elGate = document.getElementById('gate');
  var elV1 = document.getElementById('v1');
  var elV2 = document.getElementById('v2');

  var gateValue = elGate.value !== 'd' ? parseInt(elGate.value) : undefined;
  var v1Value = elV1.value === 'b1' ? false : elV1.value === 'b2' ? true : undefined;
  var v2Value = elV2.value === 'b1' ? false : elV2.value === 'b2' ? true : undefined;

  var result = 'Invalid result';

  if (v1Value !== undefined && v2Value !== undefined && gateValue !== undefined && gateValue > 0 && gateValue < 6) {
    switch (gateValue) {
      case 1:
        result = (v1Value && v2Value) ? 'true' : 'false';
        break;
      case 2:
        result = (v1Value || v2Value) ? 'true' : 'false';
        break;
      case 3:
        result = ((v1Value && !v2Value) || (!v1Value && v2Value)) ? 'true' : 'false';
        break;
      case 4:
        result = (!(v1Value && v2Value)) ? 'true' : 'false';
        break;
      case 5:
        result = (!(v1Value || v2Value)) ? 'true' : 'false';
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

```html
<select id="gate">
  <option value="d"> Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">AND</option>
  <option value="2">OR</option>
  <option value="3">XOR</option>
  <option value="4">NAND</option>
  <option value="5">NOR</option>
</select>

<select id="v1">
  <option value="d"> Please Select</option>
  <option value="b1">0</option>
  <option value="b2">1</option>
</select>

<select id="v2">
  <option value="d"> Please Select</option>
  <option value="b1">0</option>
  <option value="b2">1</option>
</select>

<input id="result">
<button id="buttonId">Run Logic</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, the logic works great but is there anyway to get this to run through a button? So only do the logic onclick ?

Comment: @Rhys Ofcourse, just bind the function to the click event of the button. I updated the snippet to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Always is a good time to innovate an answer, this is my solution:

full code at
https://codepen.io/ronald_avendano/pen/VwEKaqN

```
   const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Definir el tamaño de los cuadros en el patrón
    const cuadroSize = 10;

    // Definir colores para las líneas del patrón
    const colorLineaPrincipal = '#e5e4e2'; // Color de las líneas principales (Isabelline)
    const colorLineaSecundaria = '#f4f0ec'; // Color de las líneas secundarias
    const colorRectangulo = '#b2beb5'; // Color de los rectángulos
    const grosorRectangulo = 2; // Grosor de línea de los rectángulos

    // Obtener el tamaño del canvas
    const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    const canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    function drawPattern() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); // Borrar el canvas

        // Dibujar los puntos
        ctx.fillStyle = colorLineaPrincipal;
        const radioPunto = 2; // Tamaño del radio de los puntos
        for (let x = 0; x <= canvasWidth; x += cuadroSize) {
            for (let y = 0; y <= canvasHeight; y += cuadroSize) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, radioPunto, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
    }


    // Llama a la función para dibujar el patrón cuadriculado cuando la página se carga
    drawPattern();

    const zoomSlider = document.getElementById('zoomSlider');
    const zoomValue = document.getElementById('zoomValue');
    const canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');

    function zoomCanvas() {
        const zoomLevel = zoomSlider.value;
        zoomValue.textContent = `${zoomLevel}%`;

        // Calcula el nuevo ancho y alto del canvas según el zoom
        const newWidth = (canvas.width * zoomLevel) / 100;
        const newHeight = (canvas.height * zoomLevel) / 100;

        // Actualiza el tamaño del canvas
        canvas.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
        canvas.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;

        // Permite el overflow en el contenedor del canvas
        canvasContainer.style.overflow = 'auto';

        // Redibuja el contenido del canvas
        redraw();
    }

    function adjustShapes(scale) {
        // Ajusta las coordenadas y el tamaño de las figuras
        for (const shape of shapes) {
            shape.x *= scale;
            shape.y *= scale;
            shape.width *= scale;
            shape.height *= scale;

            for (const output of shape.outputs) {
                output.x *= scale;
                output.y *= scale;
            }

            for (const input of shape.inputs) {
                input.x *= scale;
                input.y *= scale;
            }
        }
    }

    function adjustCanvasSize(scale) {
        // Actualiza el tamaño del canvas
        canvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
        canvas.height = canvas.height * scale;

        // Ajusta el estilo del canvas para que refleje el nuevo tamaño
        canvas.style.width = `${canvas.width}px`;
        canvas.style.height = `${canvas.height}px`;

        // Habilita el overflow en el contenedor del canvas
        canvasContainer.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }

    let isEditingLabel = false; // Variable para controlar la edición del label
    let editedShape = null; // Variable para rastrear la forma en edición

    function editShapeLabel(event) {
        const mouseX = event.offsetX;
        const mouseY = event.offsetY;

        // Verifica si se hizo doble clic en una forma para editar su label
        for (const shape of shapes) {
            if (
                mouseX >= shape.x && mouseX <= shape.x + shape.width &&
                mouseY >= shape.y && mouseY <= shape.y + shape.height
            ) {
                isEditingLabel = true;
                editedShape = shape;
                const newLabel = prompt("Editar label:", editedShape.label); // Muestra un cuadro de diálogo para editar el label
                if (newLabel !== null) { // Comprueba si se ingresó un nuevo label
                    editedShape.label = newLabel;
                    redraw();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    function toggleShapeGroup(button) {
        var content = button.nextElementSibling;

        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
   
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;

    let isDrawingConnector = false;
    let startShape = null;
    let startOutput = null;
    let endShape = null;
    let endInput = null;
    let shapes = [];
    let connectors = [];

    let isDragging = false;
    let dragStartX = 0;
    let dragStartY = 0;
    let dragOffsetX = 0;
    let dragOffsetY = 0;
    let selectedShape = null;
    let selectedConnector = null;

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
        const mouseX = event.offsetX;
        const mouseY = event.offsetY;

        // Verifica si se hizo clic en un output de un shape
        for (const shape of shapes) {
            if(shape.type!="Text"){
                for (const output of shape.outputs) {
                    if (
                        mouseX >= shape.x + output.x - 6 && mouseX <= shape.x + output.x + 6 &&
                        mouseY >= shape.y + output.y - 6 && mouseY <= shape.y + output.y + 6
                    ) {
                        isDrawingConnector = true;
                        startShape = shape;
                        startOutput = output;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Verifica si se hizo clic en una forma para moverla
        for (const shape of shapes) {
            if (
                mouseX >= shape.x && mouseX <= shape.x + shape.width &&
                mouseY >= shape.y && mouseY <= shape.y + shape.height
            ) {
                isDragging = true;
                selectedShape = shape;
                dragStartX = mouseX;
                dragStartY = mouseY;
                dragOffsetX = mouseX - shape.x;
                dragOffsetY = mouseY - shape.y;
                return;
            }
        }

    });

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        if (isDragging) {
            const mouseX = event.offsetX;
            const mouseY = event.offsetY;
            selectedShape.x = mouseX - dragOffsetX;
            selectedShape.y = mouseY - dragOffsetY;
            updateConnectors(selectedShape);
            redraw();
        }
    });
```