# Different ways in checking if a number is greater than zero (0)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, type-conversion, conditional-statements, coercion

What are the differences between using **condition**, **coercion** and **Boolean conversion** in checking a number type for greater than zero (0)?

Each will give the same output

```
var zero = 0;
var three = 3;

// condition
zero > 0 //false
three > 0 //true
null > 0 //false

// coercion
zero ? true : false; //false
three ? true : false; //true
null ? true : false; //false

// Boolean conversion
Boolean(zero); //false
Boolean(three); //true
Boolean(null); //false
```

What is the difference between these operations? (In terms of speed/performance, principles, practices, etc.)

Comment: why conditional operator for already boolean values? btw, zero is falsy, and any negative number is truthy.

Comment: `zero > 0` is a boolean while `zero ? ...` is a [truthy or falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. By the way `zero > 0` <=> `zero > 0 ? true : false`

Comment: The condition expression is the only one that works if checking negative numbers, so would make more sense to use that one I guess ...

Comment: See this : http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-difference-between-boolean-objects-and-boolean-primitives-in-javascript.html

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for pointing that out. I updated it now.

Comment: @Cinn, Thanks for pointing the first two examples out. I updated it now

Comment: Btw, Am I using the right term for "coercion"? Is it different from "truthy"?

Comment: @ColdCerberus you used it well, and it is different from truthy, a good answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915864/3936644

Comment: first condition of ternary operater  needs  to be a boolean expression. But above in your case you are doing assignment not evaluating a boolean expression. So in this case whatever value is in isGreaterThanZero will be used as boolean expression on the basis of value of this variable ternary operator will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Both condition and coercion use js boolean logic (you can check ECMA-262 standard for more details), while Boolean constructor, in fact, implements this logic itself.

Therefore speed/perfomance -> Boolean() wins. Principles/practice/etc. -> depending on the codestyle you follow

Answer (score 1):

In this case, **Boolean conversion**  `isGreaterThanZero= Boolean(zero)` is best in terms of speed/performance because there is no logical condition (if..else) behind this.

And remaining methods **condition and coercion conversion** is a bit slow due to it's logical condition (if..else).

```
isGreaterThanZero= zero > 0
isGreaterThanZero= zero ? true : false
```

Answer (score 1):

The **condition** and **coercion** you've mentioned are both types of *implicit coercion*.

*Implicit coercion* refers to type conversions that aren't as readable or developer friendly. And from what I've learned, a lot of the hatred towards *implicit coercion* comes from the fact that it doesn't specify exactly what is being converted and can therefore create unexpected or unintended results.

**Boolean conversion** is *explicit coercion*, meaning that it is more readable for developers and specifies what's being converted (unlike what is implied).

I don't have solid answers on speed/performance and principles in regards to your questions, but if you're concerned about readability (for future reference or another developer) that **Boolean conversion** is the way to go.