# How to sort an object based on string

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this from which I need to sort by id.

```
64: {id: "83", name: "(83) x"}
65: {id: "84", name: "(84) y"}
66: {id: "85", name: "(85) z"}
67: {id: "86", name: "(86) a"}
68: {id: "9", name: "(9) b"}
```

I have checked many examples and I have tried them all but nothing worked for me

I tried this one first:

```
obj.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.id > b.id;
        })
```

Then,

```
obj.sort((a,b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0));
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: What is the current result of your sort? Also, you must subtract your values in a sort to actually sort them, so you should probably change them to numbers

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 the result is same as above

Comment: Try parsing the `id` while sorting? (`parseInt`)

Comment: Also, did you convert the object to an array before sorting? Because `.sort` doesn't exist on `Object`

Comment: You have *strings*, not *numbers*. Coerce them: `obj.sort((a,b) => (+a.id > +b.id) ? 1 : ((+b.id > +a.id) ? -1 : 0));`. Or simply `obj.sort((a, b) => +a.id - +b.id);`.

Comment: Wait, you are trying to sort an object? Objects aren't index based

Comment: @wentjun That's not an object, you can see by the numbers on the left that OP probably copied an array from the console.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yeah, I was pretty confused. Sorry about that. He named his variable as `obj`, hence I kinda assumed its an object.. And that those are key-value pairs

Answer (score 3):

So, something like this?

```js
let op = [{id: "83", name: "(83) x"},
    {id: "84", name: "(84) y"},
    {id: "85", name: "(85) z"},
    {id: "86", name: "(86) a"},
    {id: "9", name: "(9) b"}].sort((a,b) => {
        const nA = Number(a.id);
        const nB = Number(b.id);

        return (nA > nB) ? 1 : ((nB > nA) ? -1 : 0)
    });
    
console.log(op)
```

When you compare "83" to "9", you're comparing strings. Just like "Alfred" comes before "Zac" just because of the first letter, "83" comes before "9" just because of the first letter.

Note: As you can see from different answers and comments, your sorting function is a bit wordy. You can simplify by returning something like this `nA - nB` instead of the whole `(nA > nB) ? 1 : ((nB > nA) ? -1 : 0)`. Or you can even make it a single line function with [coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38258318/1260495) . There are a couple of answers here that use coercion, if you go that route you should accept one of their answers

Comment: I have updated your code. added code to code snippet. if you find anything not in sync of what you meant let me know or revert it back.

Comment: A simple `return nA - nB` would serve its purpose: more elegant and easy to read

Comment: @DavideVitali you're right. But I usually try to use OP's own work to answer their question. I like to provide exactly what they are missing so it's easy for them to see what they had to do. However, given that it _is_ better to have an `a - b` thing, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to force -1, 1 and 0 results, because if result is negative, order will maintain and if it positive it will swap, so you can just subtract them:

```js
let arr = [{id: "83", name: "(83) x"},
    {id: "84", name: "(84) y"},
    {id: "85", name: "(85) z"},
    {id: "86", name: "(86) a"},
    {id: "9", name: "(9) b"}];
    
    
let resp = arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id));

console.log(resp);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an alternative solution to the methods which are mentioned over here.

First, we convert the object to array. Next, we have to provide a custom sorting function. We sort it by making use of [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), and passing the `numeric: true` option to localeCompare. I have left the [locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Using_locales) as `undefined`, but you may pass in your own locale options, depending on your use case.

```js
const obj = {
  64: {id: "83", name: "(83) x"},
  65: {id: "84", name: "(84) y"},
  66: {id: "85", name: "(85) z"},
  67: {id: "86", name: "(86) a"},
  68: {id: "9", name: "(9) b"}
}

const result = Object.values(obj).sort((a,b) => {
  return a['id'].localeCompare(b['id'], undefined, {numeric: true});
});

console.log(result);
```

If you would prefer to squeeze everything onto one line,

```
const result = Object.values(obj).sort((a,b) => a['id'].localeCompare(b['id'],undefined, {numeric: true}));
```

Please read up more about JavaScript's [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, as I have noticed that you are trying to 'directly' sort an object/dictionary using JavaScript's sort. It has to be in array format.

Answer (score 2):

Your id is string so convert it to int in order to `sort` it . Use `parseInt` instead .

```js
var obj=[{id: "83", name: "(83) x"},{id: "84", name: "(84) y"},{id: "85", name: "(85) z"},{id: "86", name: "(86) a"},{id: "9", name: "(9) b"}];
obj.sort((a, b) => {
            return parseInt(a.id )> parseInt(b.id);
        });
        
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see this short solution

```
obj.sort((a,b) => +a.id-+b.id)
```

Comment: Short and sweet! This should be the accepted answer imo