# How true+false===1 evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to compare true+false to 1 i.e true+false===1

In the past, I tried the following:

```
   true===1  //false
   false===0 //false
   true-true===0 //true
```

I expect the output to be false but the actual output is true.

Comment: true+false means 1+0 and it is 1

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

true and false are implicitly type casted to number when used in mathematical operation

***Note:-*** here `+` is type casting it to number

```js
console.log(+true)
console.log(+false)
console.log(true+false)
```

so

```
true + false === 1
```

is actually

```
1 + 0 === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add up two Booleans, since the Booleans do not support arithmetic operation, but logic operation only, the JS environment just converts them to Number. So 1+0===1. But if you do true ===1, this is type sensitive, it will result false. If you do true == 1, it’ll be true. Cuz this is not type sensitive, type transformation will be done by JS environment.