# Why isn't 2+3 == "2+3"?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
var comp = 2+3;
console.log(comp == "5"); // true
console.log(comp === "5"); // false
console.log(comp == "2+3"); // false
```

Why isn't the 3rd comparison true? JS can convert a string to integer only if it's a single number? What happens in the 3rd comparison? Is it unable to convert "2+3" into a number so it just assumes it's different?

Comment: Try out in Chrome's developer tool what's the difference between `console.log("2+3")` and `console.log(2+3)`. You will see the first is resolved as `"2+3"` and the second one is `5`.

Comment: `"2+3"` can't be coerced to a number, it's a *calculation* and won't be magically evaluated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `"2+3"` is not a _calculation_ to JavaScript.  It's just a string.  That's like saying `"Hello"` is a _greeting_ -- but to JavaScript, it's not ... it's just a string.  I'm sure you understand this, but what you said could be misleading to someone who doesn't understand.

Comment: @Wyck sorry, I meant it *represents* a calculation. `"5"` is also just a string!

Comment: You could evaluate the expression: 2+3===eval("2+3"), [p.s. many disapprove of eval]

Comment: Since your question has already been answered, here's something to also be aware of. _Most_ arithmetic operators will automatically coerc numbers from strings when possible:  `"3" * "2" === 6` and `"3" - "2" === 1`, *but* the plus operator will still just concatenate the strings: `"3" + "2" === "32"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comp`, which is `5` is a number type in JS and `"5"` is a string. A string and a number are not the same and thus `console.log(comp === "5")` will return `false`.

When you use `==` instead of `===` it returns `true`, because of a concept called "**type coercion**". This just means that JS assumes that you are trying to compare two of the same types—in this case numbers—because they seem to be identical, and returns `true`. So it converted the string to a number to help you out.

In the third case there are other types of characters in the string, in addition to numbers, and none of them are similar to the number `5`, so type coercion does *not* apply and so it returns `false`.

Read more about type coercion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Because `"2+3"` with quotation marks signals javascript that this is an string and it cant be coerced to an number.

And `5` is not the same like `"2+3"`.

Just test it: `console.log(typeof '2+3')` and `console.log(typeof 2 + 3)`

Comment: Double equal doesnot check types. Tripple equal does. The reason it is `false` it is because `"2+3"` is not `5`.

Comment: @AdamOrlov actually, double equals does check types, but tries to perform coercion if types are not the same. Maybe a formulation detail, but it definitely helped me better understand that  `==` does actually _more work_ than `===`.