# jQuery invalid left-hand side error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving a console error for this line:

```
$("#note" + noteCount).val() = note;
```

Here is the full function:

```
function addNotes() {
    noteCount++;
    var note = $("#noteInput").val();
    console.log("Note: " + note);
    console.log("Note Count: " + noteCount);
    var display = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById("displayContainer").appendChild(display);
    display.className = "noteDisplay";
    display.id = "note" + noteCount;
    $("#note" + noteCount).val() = note;
}
```

As you can see i'm creating a div with id 'note' + note count but i'm not sure how to select it to change its value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597667/referenceerror-invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `textContent` property as you are creating a `DIV`

```
 var display = document.createElement("div"); 
 display.id = "note" + noteCount;
 display.textContent = note;
```

OR, [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as `DIV` doesn't have `value` property and you need to provide it as a parameter to the method call:

```
$("#note" + noteCount).text(note);
```

---

As you are using jQuery create HTML using it

```
var display = $("<div>", {
    "text" : note,
    "id" : "note" + noteCount,
    "class" : "noteDisplay"     
});

display.appendTo('#displayContainer');
```

Comment: Well spotted that it's a `div` element. I'd expand the answer to improve the logic to get rid of the `createElement`/`appendChild` ugliness too.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```
$("#note" + noteCount).val( note );
```

[val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) invocation returns a value which you cannot override with another value.

```
val = note; //has a different meaning, still not correct for your scenario
```

but

```
val() = note; //not allowed
```

since value is already computed via function call and hence left side is not a variable , but a value and you cannot assign a value to a value

Answer (score 1):

Your way of assigning the value is wrong . You need to pass it as an argument to the `val` function because its a function and not a property

```
$("#note" + noteCount).val(note) ;
```

See the **[JQUERY DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

Comment: I was confused when looking at the doc previously becuase it says 'this method does not accept any arguments'. Thank you though :)

Comment: No Problem :). Glad to help

Comment: I will in just a second yes :) I'm sure you're right but when I test it out it's not being displayed. The div is being created with the id and class name but the class isn't taking effect either

Answer (score 1):

You should put the value inside `()` of `val` when using `jQuery`;

```
$("#note" + noteCount).val(note);
```