# using Short-Circuiting ( || ) in Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, short-circuiting

this block of code takes the values of the `scored` property and puts them in `duplication` object as a key and how many times the name got duplicated as a value using the  `||` operator.
I understand that the `||` operator will return the first truthy value or the last value if all of the values are falsy, however, I didn't understand  `duplication[x]++` what does the `++` sign do exactly? and why we put the `(duplication[x]=1)` between parentheses

```
const game = {
  score: "4:0",
  scored: ["Lewandowski", "Gnarby", "Lewandowski", "Hummels"],
}; 


const duplication = {};
for (let x of game.scored) {
 duplication[x]++ || (duplication[x]=1) // I'm confused in this line
}
 
console.log(duplication);
```

Comment: `||` is not a "short circuit" operator. It's the logical "or" operator. It runs "a or b", so it runs `duplication[x]++` and if that's falsey, it then runs `(duplication[x]=1)`. Also, remember to write your post about the thing you actually want to know: if you don't know what `++` does, or why someone would add `()`, then [ask about that](/help/how-to-ask). But of course, only after searching the web/SO for explanations (which for `++` is trivial, there are thousands of pages that explain what that does).

Comment: "so it runs duplication[x]++ and if that's falsey, it then runs (duplication[x]=1)" - almost literally the definition of a short circuit evaluation; evaluation is stopped if evaluating the other side of the operator would not change the result, ie `true || x` or `false && x`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans next time I will search more before asking, Thank you for your correction about `||` .

Comment: Almost literally is not literally: JS does not call it the "shortcircuit operator", so that's not what it is when we're talking about JS. It is the [logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), which you can _use_ to short circuit a conditional. Using the right terms, and learning the right terms, when asking a technical question always matters.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think I see the grain of sand at the centre of this pearl. I would agree that `||` is not _the_ short-circuit operator, and I imagine you would agree that `||` is _a_ short-circuit operator (if not explicitly named so in ECMA-262). If not, that's fine too ✌️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-descriptive variable names don't really help to explain the situation. Let's start of by rewriting the code with more descriptive variable names.

```js
const game = {
  score: "4:0",
  scored: ["Lewandowski", "Gnarby", "Lewandowski", "Hummels"],
}; 


const goals = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  goals[player]++ || (goals[player] = 1);
}
 
console.log(goals);
```

`goals[player]++` increments the `goals` for `player` by 1 and returns the old value. The tricky thing in `goals[player]++` is that `player` might not be present in `goals` yet. In which case `undefined` is returned (which is falsy). Because the value is falsy the second operand of the OR operator will be executed. `(goals[player] = 1)` will set the `goals` for `player` to `1`.

The code is essentially counting how often a specific name is present in the `game.scored` array. The presence of a name symbolises a goal made by them.

A less cryptic way of writing similar code would be:

```js
const goals = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  if (player in goals) {
    goals[player] += 1; // add 1 to the current score
  } else {
    goals[player] = 1; // no score present so use 1
  }
}
```

However I usually prefer to set a default value, this way you don't have to split the logic into two actions:

```js
const goals = {};
for (const player of game.scored) {
  goals[player] ||= 0; // assign 0 if the current value is falsy
  goals[player] += 1;  // add 1 to the current value
}
```

Note that [`||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) is fairly new, if you write JavaScript for older browser you can use the following instead:

```js
if (!goals[player]) goals[player] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! 
I have 2 more questions please : 
1- When I was changing some stuff to understand the code I noticed that changing `duplication[x]++` to `duplication[x]+=`1 returns `NaN` and I didn't understand why It is clearly a number... 2- when I remove the parentheses from `(duplication[x]=1)` it gives this error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. Why I can't assign `duplication[x]=1` without putting it inside a parentheses.

Comment: @MrXQ 1. If `value` is not defined yet (`undefined`) then `undefined + 1 //=> NaN`. Because `value++` returns the **old** value the return value will be `undefined`. `++value` and `value += 1` do the same thing as `value++` but they return the **new** value (`NaN`) instead of the old value. Though all three scenarios do leave `value` set to the value `NaN` (which is also falsy). (1/2)

Comment: 2. The reason you cannot remove the parentheses is because `||` has a higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `=`. Therefore `goals[player]++ || goals[player] = 1` will be evaluated as `(goals[player]++ || goals[player]) = 1`, which causes the error because it is an invalid JavaScript expression. (2/2)

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what's happing on this line :

```
duplication[x]++ || (duplication[x]=1)
```

1. `duplication[x]++` , first `duplication[x]` it will check if `duplication` has any with value of `x`, if yes then it it will perform `duplication[x]++` else it will be undefined to moved to the other part of `or` condition
2. `duplication[x]=1`, this is a simple assignment it will assign the value 1, `duplication[x]` and this will create a key if not exist in the `duplication` object

Now if you run the below script and check the console log for each loop, it will give you clear idea what actually happing.

```js
const game = {
  score: "4:0",
  scored: ["Lewandowski", "Gnarby", "Lewandowski", "Hummels"],
}; 


const duplication = {};
let index = 0;

for (let x of game.scored) {

  console.log( `INDEX : ${index} ` , x , duplication[x] ? 'FOUND , INCREMENT CURRENT VALUE WITH ++' : 'NOT FOUND, SO ASSIGN VALUE 1' );
  duplication[x]++ || (duplication[x]=1)
  console.log( `INDEX : ${index} \n` , duplication);
  index++;

}
 
console.log( 'FINAL OBJECT \n' , duplication);
```

Comment: "if yes then it it will perform `duplication[x]++` else it will be undefined" - very close, it will post-increment regardless of what value is currently in `duplication[x]` but test against what is in `duplication[x]` before the increment. I'm actually not sure if that qualifies as undefined behaviour; it seems possible to me that the post increment could occur after the assignment (`duplication[x] = 1`). Personally I'd consider `duplication[x] = (duplication[x] || 0) + 1`

Comment: Yes, agreed! but I am just trying to explain the current code as OP is bit confused, your approach is better and more clear. @msbit

Comment: @VivekDoshi Thank you so much for this detailed answer, now I can understand the general idea of this line however I have two questions 
1- When I was changing some stuff to understand the code I noticed that changing `duplication[x]++` to `duplication[x]+=1` returns `NaN` and I didn't understand why, It is clearly a number... 
2- when I remove the parenthesesfrom `(duplication[x]=1)` it gives this error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment . Why I can't assign `duplication[x]=1` without putting it inside a parentheses

Comment: @MrXQ, read this one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43414179/2349407, this might help you with your queries

Answer (score 1):

The first part of

```
duplication[x]++ || (duplication[x] = 1)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

has four parts:

1. a variable `duplication` with
2. a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) `x` in bracket notation
3. a postfix [increment operator `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) and
4. an expression for the [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) operator.

The second part returns `undefined` at the first call with an unknown property.

The try to increment this value returns [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), because of the following operation of `duplication[x] = duplication[x] + 1`. The result is is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

This forces the expression to evaluate the right hand part of logical OR.

And because the left hand part has an expression, it needs to be evaluated first with a [grouping operator `()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping). Now the assignment takes place and the result of `1` is returned to the OR.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!